# How can I find my object with lodash by id?

Tags: reactjs, lodash, react-redux

I have a userData object (which comes from a redux store) that contains this:

```
"packs": [
          {
            "name": "Docos",
            "id": "101",
            "price": 1000,
            "gifted": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Entertainment Plus",
            "id": "102",
            "price": 1000,
            "gifted": false
          }]
```

I am trying to find the 1st one like this:

```
 let pack = _.find(this.props.userData.packs, 'id', "101")
```

But when I run it it says pack is undefined? why?

Comment: your code seems to be okay, https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/3398/

Comment: @QoP try to find by "102" =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read lodash documentation and watch examples

**_.find**

> Arguments
>
> collection (Array|Object): The collection to inspect.
>
> [predicate=_.identity] (Function): The function invoked per iteration.
>
> [fromIndex=0] (number): The index to search from.

1 shorthand

```
_.find(this.props.userData.packs, {id: '101'})
```

2 shorthand

```
_.find(this.props.userData.packs, ['id', '101'])
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/), the correct syntax would be one of the followings:

```
_.find(this.props.userData.packs, function(p) { return p.id === '101'; });
```

*The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.*

```
_.find(this.props.userData.packs, { 'id': '101' });
```

*The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.*

```
_.find(this.props.userData.packs, [ 'id': '101' ]);
```

Read more from **lodash** docs: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#find